# Where to Find Package "org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core"

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm desperately trying to add the Eclipse "Install New Software" dialog to my application. After days of hunting down packages / bundles and cryptic error messages, I'm at the point where the bundle `org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin` needs the package 
`org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core`, and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I suspected the plug-in `org.eclipse.osgi`, but it's not there (at least not in 3.10.0, which is needed for Java8). We're using the last production ready version of Eclipse, 3.7.

So, where is it? (Also, if someone could point out a way to find bundles by their package without mindlessly googling and hoping that someone mentions bundle and package in the same paragraph in some forum, that would be spectacular.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That package does not exist in the newer versions of Eclipse (it was in the `org.eclipse.osgi` plugin in 3.x versions). You can't take plugins from later versions of Eclipse and expect them to work in an earlier version.

The first version of Eclipse to fully support Java 8 is Eclipse 4.4 (Luna)

Comment: I'm pretty sure if I can't replace `org.eclipse.osgi` version 3.7.2 with 3.10.0 without Eclipse breaking it's not me who screwed up. API breaks are what the first digit of the version number is for.

Comment: Despite the version this is part of Eclipse 4 and OSGi was substantially rewritten between Eclipse 3 and 4.

Comment: So correct answer: Not possible with Java8 until E4 becomes usable (or much more likely, some frustrated developer starts forking Eclipse 3). And would even have been apparent if the Eclipse folks started using the same standards as everybody else.